# Spring Boot Application - 404 Not Found on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I've read a ton of questions about this already, but none of them helped. 
I'm building a very simple rest application, but the controllers are not responsing to request and I get this error:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
```

I've put `System.out` in controllers that's also not shown so the methods aren't even called.

My project stucture is:

[image]

The Application class is under `app` package.

config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {


@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());

    // Classpath scanning of @Component, @Service, etc annotated class
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(
            env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));

    // Vendor adapter
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    // Hibernate properties
    Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
    additionalProperties.put(
            "hibernate.dialect",
            env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    additionalProperties.put(
            "hibernate.show_sql",
            env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    additionalProperties.put(
            "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
            env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);

    return entityManagerFactory;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager =
            new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
            entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
}
```

controller:

```
@Controller
public class CharacterController {

@RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public  String start() {
    System.out.println("Start");
    return "Hello.";
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>xxxxxxxxxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</name>
<description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent fapp.repositorytory -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Application:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

I also tried using `@SpringBootApplication`, putting `(basePackages ={"app","app.config" etc})`, just `app`, controller class... Even moving all classes to the same package but I'm now convinced this is not the issue.

The console log ends with:

```
2018-01-27 00:08:08.291  INFO 14596 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2018-01-27 00:08:09.634  INFO 14596 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-01-27 00:08:10.584  INFO 14596 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-01-27 00:08:10.632  INFO 14596 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-01-27 00:08:10.637  INFO 14596 --- [           main] app.Application                          : Started Application in 38.878 seconds (JVM running for 39.335)
```

so it looks like it should work...

Enviroment class:

```
package org.springframework.core.env;

public interface Environment extends PropertyResolver {
String[] getActiveProfiles();

String[] getDefaultProfiles();

boolean acceptsProfiles(String... var1);
}
```

Comment: Before starting to answer your question, I highly suggest you go through some Spring doc first: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: @BenBen yeah I've read all that before and I don't really see what's missing from my app...

Comment: Can you post the content of class `Environment.java`?

Comment: @DoNhuVy added at the end. It's not my class, though, it's from spring

Comment: Need many effort for reproducing your error. You don't post properties file, don't post Java source code with import, and no database schema, no format source code carefully. Can you post your source code to GitHub, and give me a link? I will fix for you.

Comment: @DoNhuVy I've tried to cut as much irrelevant code as possible to make the question shorter. properties file just has database credentials, path to model `app.model` and hibernate driver. All of this is correct because the schema was created when I ran the app. No model classes are used anywhere in the controller so I didnt see how it's relevant.

Comment: @DoNhuVy here's a github link https://github.com/adamzimnyy/StackoverflowQuestion I've only removed my credentials from the properties file

Comment: Add your database schema (SQL file)

Comment: @DoNhuVy I don't have an SQL file, the schema was created by hibernate and it's only one class `Item`.

Comment: I am sorry. Source code and question in low quality. When I import project to my IDE, it is still error. I vote for close question.

Answer (score -1):

When you are working with Spring boot you should have in mind that it manages lot of staff for you.

You should use the Spring boot dependencies like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It is better not to provide a version so that the managed version will be used.

Your Application class should be annotated with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

The minimal setup for your project so that controller will be functional is:

`spring-boot-starter` and `spring-boot-starter-web` along with the annotated Application class.

And then you will see in your console something like this:

```
Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.demo.CharacterController.start()
```

If all this does not work, you should create a new Spring boot project, maybe with the STS plugin for eclipse or download a project with your dependencies from [here](https://start.spring.io/).

Comment: I had `starter-web` dependency for a while, it works even less than it does now. I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/KotlinDetector` exception. I replaced it with tomcat after reading some other question and it at least started up and created the database scheme. 

I did generate this project with https://start.spring.io/ adding just Jpa dependency.